# Как использовать WlanRegisterNotification с QtMessagebBox?

Tags: windows, qt

Имеется следующий код:

```
auto callback = [](PWLAN_NOTIFICATION_DATA data, PVOID a){
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr,"Q","a");
};
DWORD dwResult;
DWORD dwMaxClient = 2;      //
DWORD dwCurVersion = 0;
HANDLE hClient;
dwResult = WlanOpenHandle(dwMaxClient, NULL, &dwCurVersion, &hClient);
dwResult = WlanRegisterNotification(
    hClient,
    WLAN_NOTIFICATION_SOURCE_ACM,
    TRUE,
    callback, //WLAN_NOTIFICATION_CALLBACK
    nullptr,
    //context,
    nullptr,
    nullptr);
```

Окно появляется в нужный момент, но при нажатии кнопки ОК программа умирает.
В консоли в этот момент написано:

```
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
```

При перезапуске сообщение немного поменялось:

```
QWidget::repaint: Recursive repaint detected
QObject::setParent: Cannot set parent, new parent is in a different thread
QBackingStore::endPaint() called with active painter; did you forget to destroy it or call QPainter::end() on it?
```

Как исправить проблему?

Comment: Не вызывайте `QMessageBox` из функции, которая выполняется в не главном потоке. Для начала замените `QMessageBox` на `qDebug() << ...`

Comment: Я не понимаю почему это не главный поток. Явно с помощью QThread я его не создаю. Заменить не очень вариант, мне нужен именно QMessageBox.

Comment: Вы передаете callback функции `WlanRegisterNotification`, а потом он вызывается в другом потоке. Чтобы перейти в главный поток, используйте `QCoreApplication::postEvent`.

Comment: Не очень понимаю как это сделать. Можете пожалуйста набросать код с использованием postEvent?

Answer (score 1):

Пример использования функции `QCoreApplication::postEvent` для передачи сообщений из любого потока в главный. В примере есть два случая: сообщение без параметров и с параметрами. Для сообщения с параметрами необходимо написать класс, который наследует от `QEvent` и содержит дополнительные данные.

Сообщения обрабатываются в виртуальной функции `bool event(QEvent *evt)`, которая работает в главном потоке.

Можно использовать `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` как предложил @Pavel Gridin, см. `on_pushButtonTest2_clicked` и `showMessage`.

```
#include <thread>
#include <QMessageBox>

#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

const int eventId1 = QEvent::User + 1;      // event without parameters
const int eventId2 = QEvent::User + 2;      // custom event with parameters

class CustomEvent : public QEvent
{
public:
    CustomEvent(const char* s) : QEvent(static_cast<QEvent::Type>(eventId2)), data(s) { }
    QString getData() const {return data;}

private:
    QString data;
};


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButtonTest_clicked()
{
    std::thread t([this]()
    {
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new QEvent(static_cast<QEvent::Type>(eventId1)));
    });

    t.join();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonTest1_clicked()
{
    std::thread t([this]()
    {
        QCoreApplication::postEvent(this, new CustomEvent("message from thread"));
    });

    t.join();

}

// protected: bool event(QEvent *evt) override;
//
bool MainWindow::event(QEvent *evt)
{
    if (evt->type() == static_cast<QEvent::Type>(eventId1))
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this, "test", "eventId1");
        return true;
    }
    else if (evt->type() == static_cast<QEvent::Type>(eventId2))
    {
        auto* e = dynamic_cast<CustomEvent*>(evt);

        if (e)
        {
            QMessageBox::information(this, "test", e->getData());
        }

        return true;
    }


    return QMainWindow::event(evt);
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonTest2_clicked()
{
    std::thread t([this]()
    {
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(this, "showMessage", Qt::QueuedConnection, Q_ARG(const QString&, "message from thread (invokeMethod)"));
    });

    t.join();
}

// slot
void MainWindow::showMessage(const QString& message)
{
    QMessageBox::information(this, "test", message);
}
```

Comment: зачем же QEvent, если по смыслу Qt для этого сделаны сигналы и слоты?

Comment: @PavelGridin: сигналы и слоты - это для `QThread`, а в вопросе функция вызывается из произвольного потока, не имеющего никакого отношения к Qt. Если у вас есть пример, как использовать сигналы и слоты из `std::thread`, а не из `QThread`, покажите его.

Comment: можно вызвать слот объекта функцией `QMetaObject::invokeMethod` с аргументом `Qt::QueuedConnection` или завести переменную типа `QObject` и для неё сделать connect

Comment: @PavelGridin: я добавил пример на `QMetaObject::invokeMethod`.